# AMQP 1.0 Temporary Queues in Node.js with rhea

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, rpc, amqp

I've been using RabbitMQ for a while. I have several microservices running using a basic RPC mechanism very close to the one described in the [Rabbit tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-javascript.html). I'm trying to switch to AMQP 1.0 using rhea because I need to use Amazon MQ. However, I'm still stuck in replicating this simple pattern:

```
ch.assertQueue('', {exclusive: true}, function(err, q) {
 let corr = //some UUID
   ch.consume(q.queue, function(msg) {
     /* */
   });

ch.sendToQueue('rpc_queue',
      "TEST2",
      { correlationId: corr, replyTo: q.queue });
    });
})
```

What I'm not getting from rhea is the possibility to have temporary queue (related to client connection) and andress then the "replyTo" to those queues.

I've tried with:

```
client.open_receiver({
    source: { address: "rpc:callback", expiry_policy: "connection-close" }
  });
```

using `expiry_policy`, but it doesn't work. I'm trying even RabbitMQ with AMQP 1.0 plugin then Apache ActiveMQ.

The point is, I would like to...

1. Have a temporary (exclusive) queue that auto-drops when the client connection drops.
2. Use that temp queue (I can manually assign a temp name to it, that's not the point) to address a reply.

However, I'm neither able to obtain a temporary queue (exclusive in AMQP 0.9.1) nor use that name to address a reply.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this? can you share how ?

Comment: @vrachlin long time ago I did what I just posted below

Answer (score 1):

```
const container = require("rhea");
const _logger = require("pino")();
const nanoid = require("nanoid");

const init = ({ config, caller, resources, services, rpcs }) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let _rpcs = {};
    let _responses = {};

    const send = (sender, receiver, correlation_id, body) => {
      if (receiver.source.address) {
        sender.send({
          reply_to: receiver.source.address,
          correlation_id,
          body
        });
      }
    };

    container.on("connection_open", context => {
      //RPCS
      rpcs &&
        rpcs.forEach(sendTo => {
          let parts = sendTo.name.split(".");
          _rpcs[parts[0]] = _rpcs[parts[0]] ? _rpcs[parts[0]] : {};

          let sender = context.connection.open_sender(sendTo.name);
          let receiver = context.connection.open_receiver({
            source: { dynamic: true }
          });

          receiver.on("message", context => {
            let correlation_id = context.message.correlation_id;
            if (_responses[correlation_id]) {
              let { resolve, reject } = _responses[correlation_id];
              resolve(context.message.body);
              delete _responses[correlation_id];
            }
          });

          _rpcs[parts[0]][parts[1]] = body =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              const correlation_id = nanoid();
              _responses[correlation_id] = { resolve, reject };
              send(sender, receiver, correlation_id, body);
            });
        });

      // SERVICES
      services &&
        services.forEach(service => {
          let receiver = context.connection.open_receiver({
            source: `${resources.name}.${service.name}`,
            //credit_window: 1, //service.prefetch || 500,
            autoaccept: false
          });

          receiver.on("message", async context => {
            let request = context.message;
            let reply_to = request.reply_to;
            let payload = request.body;

            try {
              let response = {
                to: reply_to,
                body: await caller(service.responder)({ payload })
              };
              if (request.correlation_id) {
                response.correlation_id = request.correlation_id;
              }
              context.connection.send(response);
              context.delivery.accept();
            } catch (error) {
              _logger.error(error);
              context.delivery.reject();
            }
          });
        });
    });

    container.on("receiver_open", context => {
      resolve(_rpcs);
    });

    container.on("connection_error", error => _logger.error(error));

    container.connect(config.getResource("amqp"));
  });
};

module.exports = { init };
```

Answer (score 1):

In essence it boils down to this flow. Read from the bottom up as this is the logical flow of things. You begin by starting your listener that will create the dynamic queue with a random name. You then open your sender and name of the reply to queue from the `context` passed in.

```
// 'conn' is the rhea connection you have already created

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let replyToQueue;

    conn.on('message', (context) => {
        // you have received your message
        resolve(context.message);
    });

    conn.once('sendable', (context) => {
        // send a message with a reply_to header
        context.sender.send({
            reply_to: replyToQueue,
            body: 'some message content'
        });
    });

    conn.on('receiver_open', (context) => {
        // capture the name of that dynamically named queue here
        replyToQueue = context.receiver.source.address;
        conn.open_sender('queue://send.to');
    });

    // start listening to a dynamically named temporary queue
    conn.open_receiver({ source: { dynamic: true } });
}
```